# Better Practice: CheckBox DataBindings vs CheckedChanged event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a `CheckBox` that, when checked/unchecked will toggle the `Enabled` property of some other controls.  I did have my code looking something like this:

```
checkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler((o, e) => 
{
    control1.Enabled = checkBox.Checked;
    control2.Enabled = checkBox.Checked;
});
```

But today I started playing with `DataBindings` and discovered I could do this:

```
control1.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", checkBox, "Checked");
control2.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", checkBox, "Checked");
```

They seem to behave the same, but I suspect one is preferred over the other.  Or perhaps one has some unexpected behavior that may trip me up later.

Is one way better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is checked at compiled time, so I'd go with that one. I assume that if the "Enabled" property in the second example was not valid you would get a runtime error.

Comment: Also, you won't be able to "refactor" the second one automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You should notice that there is another difference:
with data binding (method 2), if the object implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and if the object.Enabled is changed outside the UI layer, the checkbox.checked state will get changed automatically.